# SQL SSIS fn_cdc_get_net_changes_{instancename} returning Error: An insufficient number of arguments

Tags: sql-server, ssis, cdc

I am using the CDC function fn_cdc_get_net_changes_{InstanceName} and passing the parameters of start_lsn, end_lsn (both binary(10) together with the parameter for @row_filter_option  being value 'all update old'.

My reasons for needing this is that generally such functions simply return the net result, or the operation 4 for updates result rows and not the operation 3 result rows.

In my case, for auditing purposes I require the result of operation 3.

The error returned is: 
Msg 313, Level 16, State 3, Line 10
An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_ ... .

Now, if I use the same start and end lsn values together with a value of 'All' for @row_filter_option, I get the expected result set for each operation 4 row.

Microsoft supplied the following material for this function: [cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_ (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510627.aspx)

I know I have to be missing something obvious, but determining what that is is frustrating me. There was a ticket opened for this some time back by another programmer but the only answer MS could come up with was that the person must have the start/end lasn parameters incorrect. I have proven mine are not, so what gives?
I came across this when researching how to alter the behaviour of the SSIS component CDC Source.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I should have added (considering I referred to the net changes) that this is the same behaviour for cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_{InstanceName} as well.

Comment: In cases like this, I generally try to simplify. Have you tried reproducing your problem in SSMS with hardcoded LSN values? My first instinct when reading your account of the problem was "it's a problem with the LSNs", so confirming that what you suspect is the problem is indeed the case is a good first step.

Comment: Ben, yep the LSNs are good as the parameter using 'All' provides returned rows with those LSNs. It's just the final parameter value that determines whether the error is raised or not.  I am testing some further items today that might provide some relief in understanding where the error is being raised, as this function appears to nest  functions below it.

Comment: I think I have to bow out then as every time I've seen that error, it's been an LSN issue (e.g. min > max, one or the other of them being null, etc). I'm interested to see what you find, though!

Comment: Ben, appreciate the response though, and the thoughts behind it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for responses, this has now been resolved. Thanks. LMan.

Comment: Don't leave me hanging… what was the issue‽

Comment: Ben,  Apologies for the delay.  OK, the brief explanation is there was an issue between keyboard and chair as there was an idiot occupying the space!  The longer explanation is the difference between using fn_cdc_get_net_changes and fn_cdc_get_all_changes and the available parameters when accessing those functions. I can say that the error message is very generic, as it is the same error message if you should provide start or end LSN parameters that are not within scope as well. The moral being: Read ALL documentation before  stepping outside the components MS supplies you to work with.